# How to insert soft return in LaTex?

Tags: line-breaking

I have one problem with my project. I want to insert soft return. If I insert \\ the text is not fully justified. Can I insert soft return like in MS Word?

[image: example]

I have no idea how to fully justify first line. I used \\ before 'It' word.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. As a non-W0rd user i have to ask, what is a soft-return?

Comment: Just let TeX decide the line breaks. The so called “soft return” is a plague.

Comment: What exactely are you trying to acieve? Are you looking for a `\linebreak`?

Comment: In your picture, the first line isn't justified either. How does ``\\`` differ from what you show in that picture?

Comment: @Sverre I think the picture shows the problem, so there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: ![example with soft return - word](http://i.imgur.com/BgFGHP8.png)
![example WITHOUT soft return at the end of line - word](http://i.imgur.com/68Zn8Ca.png)

I have no idea how to fully justify first line. I used \\\ before 'It' word.

Comment: Why would you want to "fully justify" the first line? It's clearly not wide enough to fill up the entire line -- unless you make the interword whitespace amount absurdly large. Put differently, why don't you just remove the `\\` line break and let TeX decide how the typeset the entire paragraph?

Comment: @Mico I want to "fully justify" the first line, because that is required for my project.

Comment: @Mico This is sample document in English, but I'm writing my project in Polish language, and I'm forced to wrap some words to the second line. But the problem is the same - for English and Polish documents in Latex.

Comment: I also don't understand this. If you fully justify a line that's manually broken before it reaches the end, it's just gonna look terrible.

Comment: @Sverre I want to make justification like in Microsoft Word. :)
I'm new in LateX so I ask for understanding.

Comment: @userTex The thing is, if you do it like in word, it will look like word. It will look like a murderer with an axe ran through the line, hacking the sentence into little pieces.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that I'm missing something very important. If you want to make a document look like it was generated by MS Word, why employ (La)TeX? Much more straightforward to use MS Word, isn't it?

Using `\linebreak` "works" -- but at the high cost of making the paragraph look pitiful.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % text font: Times Roman clone
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
normal spacing in paragraph:

\medskip
Mineral aerosol represents one of the largest mass fractions of the global aerosol. It consists of windblown soil and is produced mainly in the arid areas of our planet, in particular in the great deserts. Its annual production rate is estimated to be in the order of \dots

\bigskip
using \verb+\linebreak+ after first sentence:

\medskip
Mineral aerosol represents one of the largest mass fractions of the global aerosol. \linebreak It consists of windblown soil and is produced mainly in the arid areas of our planet, in particular in the great deserts. Its annual production rate is estimated to be in the order of \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: "If you want to make a document look like it was generated by MS Word, why employ (La)TeX?" The package `wordlike` already do that easily, why employ MS Word? `:)`

Comment: @Fran - `wordlike` still needs serious "help" to make a document look as amateurishly typeset as, well, you know which software suite I'm thinking about. :-)

Comment: The goal of the package  is only "look like" , not ruin everything. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Johannes_B in a comment, I used `\linebreak` instead of `\\` and my problem has gone.

Comment: I think you got downvoted here because you essentially just took one of the comments to your question and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Sverre To be honest, i don't care. Wasn't me. :-)

Comment: Your original problem has gone but you have the new problem that the line will be stretched to the point that it's unreadabe. Why not let tex wrap the lines as normal?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Unreadable? `8-)` For many people the "gold standard" is text without hyphens and ridiculous stretching (because, of course, they want a justified right margin). Only three decades of word processors have damaged seriously the typographic habits.